# How to get last inserted Row in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using postgress database and tables are of form m_table1,t_table2 ect.,
Here i want to get last inserted row.

When i search i got `getLastInsertID()` or fetch id in desc order solutions.
I tried `echo $this->ModelName->getInsertID();` and `echo $this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();` alsoWhich doesnot works for me.

Because my problem is am not using id as primary key.I am using some code as primary key which is not a number.it will be random text like 'sscd','hhbb'.
So i cant even use desc order solution.Is there any other solutions?

> I am using cakephp 2.5.1

Comment: As you are not using ID as primary key, you must be generating that random code before inserting it to DB, isn't it?

Comment: remember to always mention your cakephp version

Comment: Yes @Parixit .You are right i could use it for query.I didnt even think of it !!

Comment: @Webbie Cool! Mark may comment as accepted answer. :D

Comment: I think you should make it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are not using `id` as primary key. So you must be generating your `unique text code` before inserting in DB.

So you should use directly that instead of calling `getInsertID() / getLastInsertID()` .

Hope this helps!